# Using submit to update a $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, submit

I'm using angularjs for this project, all I'm trying to do is enter in a zipcode on one view and have the resulting weather show up on the next view when you click submit. The problem is that the $scope.zipcode is not updating with the new zipcode. If the starting code is left blank a console.log says undefined, if I put something in there the results show up for the default zip but not for anything else. Please help. Thank you.

Alright so here is my code

Routing Configs

```
/* routing configs */      

var weather1 = angular.module('weather1', ['ngRoute']);

weather1.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/show',{
        templateUrl:'templates/showWeather.html',
        controller: 'WeatherController'})
    .when('/default',{
        templateUrl:'templates/inputZip.html',
        controller: 'WeatherController'})
    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl:'templates/about.html',
        })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/default'
    });
}]);
```

Controllers

```
/* cntrls */

weather1.controller('WeatherController', function($http, $scope, $location) {
$scope.list = [];
$scope.zipcode = '';
var zip = '99114';
var urlBase = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/cf6c8139e5b43574/conditions/q/';
var call = '.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
var request = urlBase.concat($scope.zipcode,call);

$scope.submit = function(){
        if($scope.zipcode){
            $scope.list.push(this.zipcode);
            $scope.zipcode='';
            $location.path('/show');
        }
};
    $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/cf6c8139e5b43574/conditions/q/' + zip + '.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
        $scope.weather = data.current_observation;
    console.log($scope.weather);
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log('fail');
    });
});
```

inputZip.html

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type='text' name='zipcode' ng-model='zipcode' required> 
    <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Check weather' />
</form>
```

showWeather.html

```
<font size='75'>{{weather.temp_f}}</font>F;  {{weather.weather}} in {{weather.display_location.full}} <img src='{{weather.icon_url}}'>
<a href='#/default'>Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you do `location.path('/show');` you're actually creating a new instance of the controller, even though it's the same controller. This why you're losing your value. You should either make sure you don't re-initialize the controller or use a service to share data between the two controllers.

Comment: How would you recommend going about not re-initializing the controller? Would I use something other than location.path?

Comment: Actually, I think using a service to store the data/logic you share between controllers is the best approach in this case. That way you can keep adding controllers and they can all have access to the same data. As a rule-of-thumb, most business logic should go in services. I like to think of controllers as just the glue that binds the logic in my services to the HTML view.

Comment: So make two different controllers with different names and put any logic they have in common inside a service.